# how to use tablelayout in zk framework

Tags: zk

I am new to ZK framework and i am using its latest version.I am trying to use tablelayout in zul but its giving error.tried importing zkmax.jar but it did not work for me.can somebody help?
    here is the sample code:

```
<tablelayout columns="2">
    <tablechildren>
        <panel title="Table 1" border="normal" maximizable="true"
            collapsible="true" width="200px" height="200px">
            <panelchildren>Panel Content</panelchildren>
        </panel>
    </tablechildren>
    <tablechildren>
        <panel title="Table 2" border="normal" maximizable="true"
            collapsible="true" width="200px" height="200px">
            <panelchildren>Panel Content</panelchildren>
        </panel>
    </tablechildren>
    <tablechildren>
        <panel title="Table 3" border="normal" maximizable="true"
            collapsible="true" width="200px" height="200px">
            <panelchildren>Panel Content</panelchildren>
        </panel>
    </tablechildren>
    <tablechildren>
        <panel title="Table 4" border="normal" maximizable="true"
            collapsible="true" width="200px" height="200px">
            <panelchildren>Panel Content</panelchildren>
        </panel>
    </tablechildren>
</tablelayout>
Error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.zkoss.zul.impl.api.XulElement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is true, i checked it later.but i found that suggestion in zk forum and so i tried.I have found the solution. I am actually using free edition and those components are available in PE &  EE not in CE.  :) For reference http://www.zkoss.org/whyzk/Features .
Thanks Anyway..!!

Answer (score 0):

`XulElement` is normally under `zul-x.x.x.jar`.

Example :

zul.6.5.3.jar contains `org.zkoss.zul.impl.XulElement`.
As you can see its on another path.
Same for zk 7.x.x => http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/impl/XulElement.html

Now you have clashing dependencies, where a version of `zul` is to high for another dependencie.
For further help I need to know what zk jars you all use.

As you can [see in this fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2itg4qu/1-tablelayout), there is nothing wrong with your code.